# Coalition Search Algorithm

Tags: java, c++, python, c, algorithm

I am looking for an algorithm that is implemented in C, C++, Python or Java that calculates the set of winning coalitions for *n* agents where each agent has a different amount of votes. I would appreciate any hints. Thanks!

Comment: if you will found elsewhere, please publish it here..

Answer (score 3):

In other words, you have an array `X[1..n]`, and want to have all the subsets of it for which `sum(subset) >= 1/2 * sum(X)`, right?

That probably means the whole set qualifies.

After that, you can drop any element `k` having `X[k] < 1/2 * sum(X)`, and every such a coalition will be fine as an answer, too.

After that, you can proceed dropping elements one by one, stopping when you've reached half of the sum.

This is *obviously* not the most effective solution: you don't want to drop `k1=1,k2=2` if you've already tried `k1=2,k2=1`—but I believe you can handle this.

Answer (score 1):

It is nice to think of solving this by separating into two cases, recursively: Find all winning "coalitions" including the last "agent" and all of those without the last "agent". Now for each of these sub-problems the same logic can be applied, with a lower target number of votes in the case where the last "agent" is included. Stop the recursion when the target number of votes is lower or equal than zero, or when there are no more agents left.

Note that in such an algorithm, ordering the agents according to the number of votes is beneficial.

Example implmentation:

```
from itertools import combinations

def _winning_coalitions(agents, target_votes):
    """recursive solving function

    @param agents: sequence of (name, votes) pairs
    @param target_votes: minimum number of votes for a coalition
    """
    if target_votes <= 0:
        # stop the recursion
        for coalition_size in range(len(agents)+1):
            for coalition in combinations(agents, coalition_size):
                yield coalition
    elif not agents:
        pass # no agents, so no possible coalitions
    else:
        agent_name, agent_votes = agents[-1]
        agents = agents[:-1]
        for coalition in _winning_coalitions(agents, target_votes-agent_votes):
            yield ((agent_name, agent_votes),) + coalition
            if sum([votes for (name, votes) in coalition]) >= target_votes:
                yield coalition

def winning_coalitions(agents):
    """find all coalitions with at least target_votes combined votes

    @param agents: dictionary of the form: name -> number of votes
    """
    target_votes = (sum(agents.values())-1)//2+1
    agents = sorted(agents.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    coalitions = _winning_coalitions(agents, target_votes)
    return sorted([sorted([name for (name, votes) in c]) for c in coalitions])
```

And in a Python interpreter:

```
>>> agents = {"Alice": 3, "Bob": 5, "Charlie": 7, "Dave": 4}
>>> # divide sum of votes by 2, rounding up
>>> target_votes = (sum(agents.values())-1)//2+1
>>> # solve!
>>> coalitions = winning_coalitions(agents, target_votes)
>>> sorted([sorted(c) for c in coalitions])
[['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie'],
 ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'Dave'],
 ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Dave'],
 ['Alice', 'Charlie'],
 ['Alice', 'Charlie', 'Dave'],
 ['Bob', 'Charlie'],
 ['Bob', 'Charlie', 'Dave'],
 ['Charlie', 'Dave']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrange the number of votes for each of the agents into an array, and compute the partial sums from the right, so that you can find out SUM_i = k to n Votes[i] just by looking up the partial sum.

Then do a backtrack search over all possible subsets of {1, 2, ...n}. At any point in the backtrack you have accepted some subset of agents 0..i - 1, and you know from the partial sum the maximum possible number of votes available from other agents. So you can look to see if the current subset could be extended with agents number >= i to form a winning coalition, and discard it if not.

This gives you a backtrack search where you consider a subset only if it is already a winning coalition, or you will extend it to become a winning coalition. So I think the cost of the backtrack search is the sum of the sizes of the winning coalitions you discover, which seems close to optimal. I would be tempted to rearrange the agents before running this so that you deal with the agents with most votes first, but at the moment I don't see an argument that says you gain much from that.

Actually - taking a tip from Alf's answer - life is a lot easier if you start from the full set of agents, and then use backtrack search to decide which agents to discard. Then you don't need an array of partial sums, and you only generate subsets you want anyway. And yes, there is no need to order agents in advance.

Comment: The OP want to find all possible "coalitions", so the order doesn't matter (rearranging won't give any benefit).